# How to secure node media server admin panel with username and password and each streamer keys - Node Media Server

Tags: node.js, live-streaming, node-media-server

First of that, thanks to the team which has created this wonderful project for live streaming.

It works more than what i expected.

The only problem is that both streamer keys and the admin panel is open to the world

So anyone can see the admin and anyone can live stream to my server with any streamer key

How to secure that?

[image: Text]

Comment: Found any solution for this, and maybe allow users to login before accessing stream?